# wso2 carbon hacking - eclipse development environment set up steps

Tags: wso2

It would be great if the carbon source tree could be set up in eclipse so that eclipse can be used for building and running carbon.  Is this possible?  How do the WSO2 carbon developers set up their development environments?

For example based on eclipse 4.3 RC2 Java EE:

1. `$ svn checkout http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0 wso2carbon`
2. `$ cd wso2carbon`
3. `$ mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`  (first ensure you have enough permgen space, e.g. `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M`)
4. `$ mvn eclipse:eclipse`
5. ensure eclipse M2_REPO variable points to your `~/.m2/repository` folder
6. import all'dependencies/axiom' sub-projects into eclipse (Existing Projects into Workspace)
7. select all maven projects, right click and `Disable Maven Nature`
8. repeat step 6 and 7 for which projects???

What are the steps?  Should I expect errors be shown (see screenshot, below) in the eclipse error window after the import has completed and eclipse build has finished?

[image: build errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing, you need to set the classpath. for that,buildpath-->configure buildpath, you will see libraries are listed under M2_REPO,folder.
So, you might need to create a variable called M2_REPO,its path has to point your local m2-repository;
eg:

```
Name: M2_REPO
path: C:/Users/TOSH/m2-repo/repository
```

Comment: I already had the M2_REPO variable setup, but still have build errors (I have added a screenshot to my question showing the errors).  Am I importing the right projects?

Comment: i normally dont do steps 6 and 7. If you point the m2 repo, project will start to build..and resolve all the classpath issues

Comment: So do you just checkout the project directly using eclipse, and not command line svn?

Comment: using command line svn, take checkout and build first , then use mvn eclipse:eclipse then import as existing project, set classpath

Comment: still not working :(  Is this all that is required - I must be missing the point somewhere.  Are there any more detailed instructions anywhere?

Comment: you can try first a simple module and see..eg: in carbon-core select util package and build as i mentioned and try to import it to eclipse..(May be a big project has issue..)

Comment: thanks for your persistence with me!!   Don't WSO2 developers check out and import the whole source tree then?

Comment: i think, we haven't tried the whole tree, since developers work with single/some multiple modules..we try to import only those modules and continue development..if there is an issue with a whole source, then pls create jira.