# How to configure WSO2 Governance Registry into Developer studio IDE?

Tags: wso2

I have built the source code (4.5.3). I have built it in the order orbit and all its patch releases and kernel and all its patch releases and platform and built directly greg 4.5.3 version and my built was successful. But, how can I configure that in developer studio IDE ?
I am trying to import as Existing WSO2 Projects into workspace and I started importing orbit first and then kernel, so after importing kernel I have many build path errors like 'Project 'kernel_4.0.5' is missing required library: 'core/feature-manager/org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core/4.0.0/target/org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.core-4.0.0.jar' and like wise many of them. And When I try to import platform I am getting - resource'/${artifactId}' already exits. So, how to configure WSO2 Governance Registry(4.5.3) into IDE ?? Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927636/wso2-carbon-hacking-eclipse-development-environment-set-up-steps) - in particular read the comments.

I don't think WSO2 developers import the whole source tree into eclipse, instead they only import the maven modules that they need to work on.  Also, don't import the modules into eclipse using the maven eclipse plugin.  Instead, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the module and then import the module as a **general** project.  Don't import as a maven project.

Comment: Thanks Chris. So, Can you tell me what I will be importing for WSO2 Governance Registry(4.5.3) ? Is that just that module ? But still it has dependencies that come from kernel right ? Can you suggest me ?

Comment: @VenkatJanyavula - What you need to import will depend on what your goal is.  What are you ultimately looking to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Chris for your quick reply.. I am looking to customize and looking to change functionality for Governance Registry (its one of the products).. So for that, I have built the whole source code and I wonder, how to configure Registry in to the IDE and also I have to debug the Registry ?

Comment: @VenkatJanyavula - It may be worth you starting with the Carbon 4.1.0 source code, and understand that before you jump into the Governance Registry which is built on top of Carbon.  This [link](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2010/08/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components) is quite helpful to understand the components model that is used to build WSO2 products.